# Facebook API - Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using facebook sdk in my website. It was working fine,but suddenly started giving problem

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

my code is

```
    require_once 'facebook/src/facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook (array(
         'appId'  => '**************',
         'secret' => '***************************'  
));

 $user = $facebook->getUser();
 $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
```

It is giving error on line `$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');`

I searched for similar question on stackoverflow. But solution was looking to be for older version of sdk.

What's can be the problem?Please help.

Comment: Did you add your current website url to your facebook application from facebook developers webpage?? Under App Domains in the Settings tab on the left

Comment: facebook access tokens expire, so you need to renew it! https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/

Comment: first get the access token by -  $token = $facebook->getAccessToken(); then use getUser().

Comment: Where do you hanlde the OAuth mechanisms? If this is all of your code, this can't work!

Comment: @alexandros: yes everything is fine. In  fact my functionality was working properly as per my expectation. But it is giving problem from just today

Comment: @fire : the information in that link is said to be outdated

Comment: @Tobi: This is just part of my code. and code is giving problem on  $facebook->api('/me','GET'); line. Another issue i observed is that $user always echoes 0,even if i am logged in facebook

Comment: _“$user always echoes 0,even if i am logged in facebook”_ – that’s because you failed to get a _new_ access token after the previous one has expired. To be logged in to Facebook itself is _not enough_ when using server-side login – you have to send the user through the login flow again to generate a fresh token.

Comment: +1 @CBroe. You have to go through the complete login flow as outlined at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0

Comment: yes i've gone thorough login flow on previous page(i have not mentioned in code here). Again i need to say that, it all was working fine till yesterday.